# Cannot get height of li tag exactly when use html to append new li html to page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a list li what I will append to page after requesting to an API, and I have to scale the padding of li to make the all of the list display fit in one screen with 3 columns.

I will get all of the li height and calculate padding. But my problem is when I load my local HTML file, the height is not exact. If I resize my browser's window, It works perfectly.

I researched and found out that when all of li HTML were added, the li height would not be updated immediately. If I get li height after a timeout(1000), I will get li height exactly.

```js
$(window).resize(function(e) {
  //adjustScreen
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  //generate li html and add to ul
  $(list_element).append(ul_contents)
  .ready(function () {
      $(window).resize();
  });
});
```

```css
#list {
  margin: 0 0 0 2%;
}

#list li {
  width: 30%;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 2%;
  /* padding:3% 2% 3% 0; */
  font-size: 4.375vw;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  border-bottom: 1px #BABABA solid;
}

#list li div.ph_img {
  float: left;
  margin: 0px 3% 0px 0px;
  width: 30%;
}

#list li div.ph_img img {
  width: 100%;
}

#list li span.position {
  display: block;
  padding: 0px;
  font-size: 1.4vw;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  margin: 0px;
}

#list li span.name {
  display: block;
  padding: 0px;
  font-size: 2vw;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  margin: 0px;
}

#list li span.floor {
  display: block;
  padding: 0px;
  font-size: 1.2vw;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.6em;
  margin: 0px;
}

#list li span.green {
  float: right;
  width: 67%;
  background-color: #00923A;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 2vw;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1.7em;
}

#list li span.red {
  float: right;
  width: 67%;
  background-color: #FF0000;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 2vw;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1.7em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="list">
  <li class="clearfix">
    <div class="ph_img"><img src="xxxxxxxxxxxx" alt=""></div>
    <span class="position">xxxxxxxxxxxx</span>
    <span class="name">xxxxxxxxxxxx</span>
    <span class="floor">xxxxxxxxxxxx</span>
    <span class="status red" device-id="013">xxxxxxxxxxxx</span>
  </li>
  <li class="clearfix">
    <div class="ph_img"><img src="xxxxxxxxxxxx" alt=""></div>
    <span class="position">xxxxxxxxxxxx</span>
    <span class="name">xxxxxxxxxxxx</span>
    <span class="floor">xxxxxxxxxxxx</span>
    <span class="status red" device-id="013">xxxxxxxxxxxx</span>
  </li>
  <li class="clearfix">
    <div class="ph_img"><img src="xxxxxxxxxxxx" alt=""></div>
    <span class="position">xxxxxxxxxxxx</span>
    <span class="name">xxxxxxxxxxxx</span>
    <span class="floor">xxxxxxxxxxxx</span>
    <span class="status red" device-id="013">xxxxxxxxxxxx</span>
  </li>
  <li class="clearfix">
    <div class="ph_img"><img src="xxxxxxxxxxxx" alt=""></div>
    <span class="position">xxxxxxxxxxxx</span>
    <span class="name">xxxxxxxxxxxx</span>
    <span class="floor">xxxxxxxxxxxx</span>
    <span class="status red" device-id="013">xxxxxxxxxxxx</span>
  </li>
  <li class="clearfix">
    <div class="ph_img"><img src="xxxxxxxxxxxx" alt=""></div>
    <span class="position">xxxxxxxxxxxx</span>
    <span class="name">xxxxxxxxxxxx</span>
    <span class="floor">xxxxxxxxxxxx</span>
    <span class="status red" device-id="013">xxxxxxxxxxxx</span>
  </li>
  <li class="clearfix">
    <div class="ph_img"><img src="xxxxxxxxxxxx" alt=""></div>
    <span class="position">xxxxxxxxxxxx</span>
    <span class="name">xxxxxxxxxxxx</span>
    <span class="floor">xxxxxxxxxxxx</span>
    <span class="status red" device-id="013">xxxxxxxxxxxx</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

My get li height function

```
function getLIHeightOfRow(index) {
  var max_li_height = 0;
  //0, 1, 2
  for (var i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
    let li_element = $(list_li_element).get(3 * index + i);

    if (li_element != undefined) {
      //plus border height 1px
      let height = Math.ceil($(li_element).height()) + 1;
      console.log("li height " + (3 * index + i) + " - " + height);
      if (height > max_li_height) {
        max_li_height = height;
      }
    }

  }
  console.log(max_li_height);
  return max_li_height;
}
```

Have any synchronous way to run a function after append li html to ul? callback?

Comment: Have you tried using `getComputedStyle()`?

Comment: $($('#list li')[index]).height();

Comment: @guest271314 in jquery, `getComputedStyle()` has been used.

Comment: I don’t see why this would need any dynamic height calculations and adapting of the padding to begin with … this sounds like a classic use case for flexbox.

Comment: @04FS depend on API, the number of li tags will be changed. In order to, display all li fit on a screen, I have to get dynamic height to change the padding to adjust li tag.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's height method returns the calculated height.

```
$($('#list li')[index]).height();
```

Comment: Are this and `$($('#list li').get(3 * index + i)).height();` have any difference?

Comment: What is list_li_element?

Comment: It is a string `"#list li"` only.